# Checking more than two conditions in if statement

Tags: bash

How to give two or more conditions in if statement in bash shell script.Here I have a variable named `opt`. If `opt` value is `1` or `2` or `3`, the if block should execute otherwise else block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
if [[ $opt =~ ^[123]$ ]]
then
  echo foo
else
  echo bar
fi
```

hat tip [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15630740)

Answer (score 2):

The classic way to do that would be the `case` statement:

```
case "$opt" in
([123]) do-then-thing;;
(*)     do-else-thing;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
if [ cond1 ] || [ cond2]; then
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the or operator of test (often called [)

```
 opt=2; if test $opt -eq 1 -o $opt -eq 2; then echo "hello"; fi
```